# How to forward URLs in TomCat

Tags: tomcat, webserver

We are moving a website from IIS to TomCat. For HTTPS, IIS uses port 443, but we are told that TomCat uses port 8443. Can you tell TomCat to use port 443 or do we need to do a redirect from port 443 to port 8443? Ultimately, we want to allow the user to be able to enter the following:

app.domain.com and have it redirect to https://app.domain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2

I was going to give another example, but I am only permitted to post one.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

If ports 80 and 443 are not still in use, you can change the default ports 8080 and 8443 in [Tomcat]/conf/server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443" connectionTimeout="20000"/>

<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="tomcat"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Be sure to change the "redirectPort" attribute as well. You also need a keystore to make ssl work, as described [in the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). A short version to create one would be this:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keypass tomcat -storepass tomcat
```

(Includes bad passwords, which need to be changed in server.xml as well, see above).